# Print HTML Files from .NET 2.0 App

Tags: c#, .net, html, printing

What's the best method for printing a directory of HTML files in landscape orientation? I don't mind showing a print dialog or not. I've tried several solutions (exhausting Google & StackOverflow) which either print the HTML as a string, or can't print in landscape.

I'm using a .NET 2.0 Win Forms project to create HTML reports. Now I need to send them to the printer spool.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12799/Print-HTML-in-C-with-or-without-the-web-browser-co ?

Comment: @reuben - I have tried that sample project, how can I print in Landscape orientation?

Comment: Look at the MSDN docs for OLECMDID (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691264(v=vs.85).aspx); there's an option for displaying "Print Preview" which lets you (through the UI) select landscape...

Comment: I would then have to show the UI for every HTML report in the directory?

Comment: Please be clearer in what you're asking. Your original request indicated that you were okay displaying the print dialog.

Comment: I am OK with showing the print dialog. But for every report in a directory? Lets say there's 20. Would you, as a user be happy configuring a dialog 20 times? I assumed you too thought this nonsensical? If that's the case I might as well go print directly from the directory via a right click on every file? Which makes this whole post pointless.

Comment: I wouldn't do that either, but if you don't provide enough context, I can't read your mind to figure out what you're really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Update :

After understanding the requirement correctly following can be achieved

```
//The example is using WebBrowser Control Version 4.0.0.0  .NET Component
//MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6(v=vs.80).aspx

//Example 1 : You can print html string using the Web Browser Control

    string htmlString = "<html><head><title>Printing from Win forms - Web Browser Control</title></head><body><h1>Hello World....</h1></body></html>";
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = htmlString;

//Example 2 : Print file or URL using the Web Browser Control

    webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq");

//Call Print function or Print Dialog

    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintFile);

    private void PrintFile(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //You can setup page e.g. Orientation to Landscape and choose one of the Print options below
        (WebBrowser)sender).ShowPageSetupDialog();

        // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
        ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

        //OR
        (WebBrowser)sender).ShowPrintDialog();

        //OR Even better setup print options and then Print
        (WebBrowser)sender).ShowPrintPreviewDialog();

        // Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
        ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: This method prints the HTML as a string which isn't what I'm looking for. And why I explicitly stated that in my question.

Comment: You also say this "I don't mind showing a print dialog or not." in your question above and based on that I gave you solution

Comment: Yeah I don't mind the dialog, but the idea behind my question was to print HTML, not text strings...

Comment: So If I got it correctly is you want render html and print it for e.g.  I print the current SO page it will print the rendered html output not HTML string of this page

Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. But the files I wish to print are generated by my program and stored locally. Oh and they must print in landscape orientation.

Comment: Thanks HatSoft for taking time to list this - I have already tried this method.. How would I go about printing in landscape orientation in your updated solution?

Comment: I have updated the post now it gives option to change page orientation with ShowPageSetupDialog or directly with ShowPrintPreviewDialog

Comment: this solution too would reqiure me to show the dialog for every report in the directory? I will mark as answer since this does work, but it's not quite what I am looking for. Thanks

Comment: If any way you can inject the CSS @media print{@page {size: landscape}} in your html string it should set page orientation to landscape then all you will need is to call .Print() method ( no dialogs will be appear). Please let me know the output